# Dynamically Creating u-strings in Python

Tags: python-2.x

https://docs.python.org/2/tutorial/introduction.html#unicode-strings

I'm currently trying to figure out how to dynamically create u-strings (which are in the form of u'helloWorld' for example). I'd like to create a u-string with string concatenation or string injection if it were possible, to use a variable to dynamically create a new u-string such as u'{variableName}'. Is there a way to accomplish this?

The usage of the Python 2 u-strings are for usage of the gcloud functions, where I'm trying to dynamically add documents. The documentation makes use of u-strings and can be found at:

https://firebase.google.com/docs/firestore/manage-data/add-data

Comment: Strings vs. unicode strings only makes sense in Python 2, and Python 2 seldom makes sense in 2021. What are you trying to accomplish? (In fairness, Apple has muddied the waters by making Python 2 their default for way too long).

Comment: Are you actually using Python 2?  In Python 3, all strings are Unicode.  They're managed just like regular strings.

Comment: *Why are you doing a tutorial for Python 2*?

Comment: What have you tried that isn't working?  `mys = u"one" + u"two"` should work fine in Python 2.

Comment: Python 2 reached its [end of life on January 1, 2020](https://www.python.org/doc/sunset-python-2/). And all strings are [u-strings by default in Python 3](https://docs.python.org/3/howto/unicode.html) if I'm not wrong.

Comment: Sorry, it may have been more clear if I added that I was trying to follow the gcloud documentation for Python, I will add that to the question.

Comment: @cloudxleaf It is understandable to use a reasonable-looking tutorial, but Python 3 vs. Python 2 is an important distinction, with Python 2 now being a niche language. Other than for reasons of maintaining old code, you are misdirecting your efforts if you spend time working through a Python 2 tutorial.

Comment: @JohnColeman That makes sense, thank you for your (and everyone else's) feedback and help. I'll see if Google has any documentation on Python3 for Firestore/Firebase and why they may have still chosen Python2 documentation.

Comment: @cloudxleaf I looked at that firebase documentation, and you are correct that their Python examples of using the API are Python 2 examples. Hopefully Python 3 (without the `u` before the string literals) will work the same. If not, this might be one of those niche cases where Python 2 is required to use an older library.

Answer (score 1):

u-strings don't exist anymore in Python 3. They are the same as normal strings. So just use normal strings.

```py
# Python 3
>>> u'Hello'
'Hello'
```

Do not use Python 2 as it is no longer supported. If you insist on using Python 2, try:

```py
# Python 2
>>> unicode('Hello')
u'Hello'
```

Comment: It's for use in gcloud functions (https://firebase.google.com/docs/firestore/manage-data/add-data), I don't have another way around it.

Comment: @cloudxleaf OK, it is just a weird way to write normal strings then. Just use a normal string.